# What is the preferred approach with regards to unit testing and dates?

Tags: java, unit-testing, date

I have a class which calculates a date and I'm wondering how best to test this.  I've come up with two approaches and wonder about your thoughts on which is 'better' (and of course, any other ingenious ideas you may have).

For example, in my code, if no condition is met then a default date of one year and one month from today is returned.

Approach #1:
Duplicate the date calculation logic in the unit test:

```
DateMidnight expectedDefaultDate = new DateMidnight().plusYears(1).plusMonths(1);
assertEquals(expectedDefaultDate , unit.getExpireDate());
```

Approach #2:
Inject 'today' as a fixed point in time and hard code expected response date:

```
DateMidnight fixedPointInTime = new DateMidnight(2011, 06, 05);
unit.setToday(fixedPointInTime);
DateMidnight expectedDefaultDate = new DateMidnight(2012, 07, 05);
assertEquals(expectedDefaultDate, unit.getExpireDate());
```

I'm quite torn over these.  I'm not big on code duplication, but the first approach is more clear to me as to what is expected.  Which would you use (if any) and why?

Comment: FYI, the “midnight”-related classes and methods in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 were deprecated. Supplanted by the [`DateTime::withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) method.

Comment: FYI… In the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes which now supplant Joda-Time, you can pass alternate subclasses of the [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class to provide artificial date-time values for testing. You could write your subclass, but static factory methods provide a few useful clocks. For example, [`fixed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) reports a specified frozen moment. See also `offset`, `tick…`, and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, Unit tests should have the following attributes:

1. be repeatable
2. test "interesting" cases

In terms of dates, using "today" is bad as it is different each day you run the test. "Interesting" cases for dates usually involve weekends, holidays, end-of-month/year, etc.

One example that has bitten me in the past: date based tests that work until, one day just before an important release you work through the weekend and find lots of tests that (unexpectedly) fail. If you are working through the weekend you are already under lots of stress and really don't need failing tests to add to the "fear, uncertainty and doubt"!

In summary, don't use "today". If you really want to test every date then don't do it day-by-day, instead code for it in the test running a loop out for a date range that extends from a fixed start date to a date beyond the expected lifetime of the system (and then some).

Comment: Good points.  You've just reminded me of a recent bug which bit us because of the time change to British Summer Time (BST). I'll take it read that you are more in support of approach 2 then.

Comment: Most definitely #2. #1 isn't guaranteed to be repeatable and is unpredictably interesting. Testing "today" is already too late if you've got a live system.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of unit tests is to find bugs. I suggest you take the approach which you think is the most likely to find an error.  Plain duplication of the code, may not find all errors. However, if you change the original code (to make it more efficient for example) the example may no longer be duplicated.

IMHO, The best thing to do is to write it both ways and either could break under different changes.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is better.
The test code should be very simple and stupid, the tested code should be intelligent and complicated. If the test code is too smart, and the test fails, you will never know if the bug is in the tested code or in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case there isn't only code duplication, there is also data hardcoding. I preffer the first approach.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by code duplication in the second approach.  there is no code there which also exists in the production code, unlike the first approach.

Comment: Well, there is no classic code duplication, but you are forced to take into account changes in many places. This isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two things to test here:

1. The class correctly calculates one month and one year from today
2. The returns date of one year and one month from today under certain circumstances.

Clearly, for #1, you need to use hard-coded values. For the latter now you can repeat the code.

Just my thought, though I wonder this is nit-picking.